# MySQL IF Statement?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a big giant sql query where I select and format a bunch of rows for export into Excel. And I want to add one more role, pretty much if the rid (role id) EXISTS and IS 3 then set it to be Role 1 otherwise set it to be Role 2.

Mysql Query Currently

```
SELECT uc_orders.billing_first_name AS 'First Name', uc_orders.billing_last_name AS 'Last 
Name', users.name AS 'Username', uc_orders.billing_street1 AS 'Address', 
uc_orders.billing_city AS 'City', uc_zones.zone_name AS 'State',uc_orders.billing_postal_code
 AS 'Postal Code', ROUND(uc_orders.order_total,2) AS 'Order Total'  FROM uc_orders, users,
 uc_zones WHERE uc_orders.uid!='0' AND uc_orders.uid = users.uid AND uc_orders.billing_zone =
 uc_zones.zone_id AND uc_orders.modified BETWEEN '1271124575' AND '1274978899'
```

HOWEVER the user will not ALWAYS exist in the users_role database (it only exists if it is 3 or some other number, normally it will not exist). So if it does not exist, it would also return 'Role 2';

So

```
  IF users.uid EXISTS IN users_role.uid THEN
    IF users_role.uid EQUALS users.uid AND users_role.rid = 3
      THEN
        return 'Role 1'
      ELSE
        return 'Role 2';
  ELSE return 'Role 2';
```

How can I do this in MySQL? Or would PHP be the only way?

Comment: Fix your question title please. Make it describe your question.

Comment: How does it not? I want to do an IF statement in a MySql Statement?

Comment: The title lists (a) a widely-used technology and (b) an incredibly generic feature. There is nothing to make it stand out from other questions, there is nothing that identifies the manner in which this question is different from other questions, and nobody would ever be able to use it to find a solution if they had the same problem as you. You might as well have written "computers question"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using `JOIN` for multi-table queries. Also consider formatting your query and using aliases for easier reading.

```
SELECT
    `a`.`billing_first_name` as `First Name`,
    `a`.`billing_last_name` as `Last Name`,
    `b`.`name` as `Username`,
    `a`.`billing_street1` as `Address`,
    `a`.`billing_city` as `City`,
    `c`.`zone_name` as `State`,
    `a`.`billing_postal_code` as `Postal Code`,
    ROUND(`a`.`order_total`,2) as `Order Total`,
    IF(`d`.`rid` IS NOT NULL AND `d`.`rid`=3,'Role 1','Role 2') as `Role`
FROM `us_orders` as `a`
JOIN `users` as `b` ON `a`.`uid`=`b`.`uid`
JOIN `uc_zones` as `c` ON `a`.`billing_zone`=`c`.`zone_id`
LEFT JOIN `users_role` as `d` on `a`.`uid`=`d`.`uid`
WHERE `a`.`modified` BETWEEN '1271124575' AND '1274978899'
```

The part that answers your actual question is the line with the `IF` and the one with the `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a CASE statement.    `CASE(rid) WHEN 3 THEN 'Role 1' ELSE 'Role 2' END;`

Info on the CASE statement can be found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case)

```
    -- Kolinks SQL using a CASE statement
    SELECT
        `a`.`billing_first_name` as `First Name`,
        `a`.`billing_last_name` as `Last Name`,
        `b`.`name` as `Username`,
        `a`.`billing_street1` as `Address`,
        `a`.`billing_city` as `City`,
        `c`.`zone_name` as `State`,
        `a`.`billing_postal_code` as `Postal Code`,
        ROUND(`a`.`order_total`,2) as `Order Total`,
        CASE (`d`.`rid`) WHEN 3 THEN 'Role 1' ELSE 'Role 2' END; as `Role`
    FROM `us_orders` as `a`
    JOIN `users` as `b` ON `a`.`uid`=`b`.`uid`
    JOIN `uc_zones` as `c` ON `a`.`billing_zone`=`c`.`zone_id`
    LEFT JOIN `users_role` as `d` on `a`.`uid`=`d`.`uid`
    WHERE `a`.`modified` BETWEEN '1271124575' AND '1274978899'
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is an IF statement.  There's also an IF() function.  Here's the MySQL reference page for the IF statement:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if-statement.html